# Python: Regex Search Special Characters giving errors while searching multiple characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, search

I am using a simple regex string search with findall() function of the package. 
In carrying out my unit tests with negative scenarios I found out that some of the special characters are returning error codes which are given in the comments below after # symbol.
My question is why are these characters returning error codes and how can I replace them with search string with escape sequence? 
Please show me the code to replace the escape sequences:

```
import re
search="database"
search="c++" # error: multiple repeat
search="c\+\+" #working
search="c+"  #working
search="c#" #working
search="j!!" #working
search="x$$" #working
search="++j" #error: nothing to repeat
search="~~c" #working
search="c@@" #working
search="j##" #working
search="c%%"  #working
search="j&&"  #working
search="j**" #error: multiple repeat
search="j*"  #* is wild card
search="c(github)" #working
search="c--" #working
search="c==" #working
document="i did c++ programming. I am a c++ programming enthusiast. I love 
working on c++ algirithms. I have experience in 3.5 years of c++ programming 
skills "
n=len(re.findall(search,document))
print("Keyword Frequency: ",search ," Count:  ",n)
```

The output of the last statement of code print() is given against each search term for easy understanding.
Solution I need has to have the ability:

1. Recognize the special character sequence. (for example it could be: ++ or +++ or +++++ or "++j" or "j**" etc
2. After recognizing the special character sequence the solution code should replace special characters with "++" or "+++" or "+++++" or "++j" or "j**"
3. Create the new search string

Thanks in advance for your solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex module comes with a function just for that: `re.escape()`. So:

```
import re

search = "c++"
# ...
document = """i did c++ programming. I am a c++ programming enthusiast. I love 
working on c++ algirithms. I have experience in 3.5 years of c++ programming 
skills """
n = len(re.findall(re.escape(search), document))
print("Keyword Frequency: ", search, " Count:  ", n)
```

should do just fine... Now, why are you using regex instead of `str.count()` for such a simple task is a question you need to answer yourself.